# Use AppleScript to send all emails in a folder at a certain time

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, applescript, automator

I'd very much like to please develop an AppleScript to send all emails inside a specific mailbox whenever it is run. Then I can create a mailbox called "9AM", place emails inside there, and with a little help from cron/iCal, have all those emails send at 9am each day allowing me to type emails late at night but have them send in the morning.

My code below however fails on the send command.

```
tell application "Mail"
    repeat with theMessage in (every message of (mailbox "9AM" of account "accountnamehere"))
        send theMessage
    end repeat
end tell
```

I also tried moving them to the "Outbox" mailbox but that just seems to make them disappear...

```
tell application "Mail"
    repeat with theMessage in (every message of (mailbox "9AM" of account "accountnamehere"))
        set mailbox of theMessage to mailbox "Outbox"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Any suggestions anyone? Help greatly appreciated!

This setup would be ideal as I can just leave a Mac switched on and then even save emails to this "9AM" mailbox from my iPhone. I hope it is possible.

Comment: It might be more helpful if you'd include the actual error message(s) you're getting.

Comment: It complains at the "send" command is unknown

Comment: The _send_ command acts on an _outgoing message_, which is a _new email message_, not one that has been saved to a _mailbox_. If you manually open, double-click, a message in the 9AM _mailbox_ you'll notice two things, there is no _Send message_ icon on the _Toolbar_ and on the _Message_ menu there is no _Send_ command, only _Send Again_ for which there is not a command in the Mail AppleScript Dictionary.

Comment: Is there please any way to migrate the message back to a send email?

Comment: I'd be equally happy to have whatever emails are inside my "Drafts" folder to send out at 9am

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily meant to be a complete answer and is too much as a comment. Because the Mail AppleScript Dictionary lacks some *verbs*, e.g. `send again`, one therefore needs to workaround any shortcomings.

The *code* below could be incorporated into your *script*. It uses *System Events* to manipulate *menu* commands to *send* composed messages from the designated *mailbox*.

**Example Code:**

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    repeat with theMessage in (every message of (mailbox "9AM"))
        open theMessage
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Send Again" of menu "Message" of menu bar 1 of process "Mail"
        delay 1
        tell application "System Events" to click menu item "Send" of menu "Message" of menu bar 1 of process "Mail"
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

What this does is automate the tasks that one could/would do manually to achieve the same results, sending the unsent saved messages from a given *mailbox*.

What this doesn't do is, if the *mailbox* is other then *Drafts*, remove the messages from the target *mailbox* and additional coding will be required.

**Notes:**

The problem with automating a series of manual tasks in this manner, aka. UI programming, is if at the designated time the *script* runs and you are doing something else and it take focus away from Mail then the *script* will not be able to properly complete.  This is because if the Mail menu is not visible then the calls being made by System Events cannot be completed.

The value of the `delay` command may need to be adjusted, e.g. `delay 1.25`, if required or whatever value works on your system.  Slower systems need higher *delay* values.

Obviously if the target *mailbox* is *Drafts* keep in mind that unless you *code* accordingly all *messages* in the target *mailbox* will be sent and therefore using e.g. "9AM" allows keeping drafts that aren't ready to send from being sent. The disadvantage of other then using *Drafts* is requiring additional coding to remove the *messages* that have now been sent via Send Again > Send in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this post, when I tried to do the same as you asked for.
Well I wasn't that happy with the other solution, so I tried it on my own.

I had no prior experience with Apple Script, but this is how i got it the sending of mails to work (check out the **Solution** chapter).

### Sending mails

This works by **copying** the content of every mail in the given mailbox (in this case `8AM`) and creating a new one with the same content. After sending the Mail, the one in the mailbox is **deleted**. However I was not able to copy the attachments over.

**Code:**

```
on sendMail(mbox)
    tell application "Mail"
        
        -- Readout all mails of inbox
        set allMails to message of mailbox ("INBOX/" & mbox) of account "yourmail_account"
        
        -- Display msg when no mail is in inbox
        if allMails is {} then
            display dialog "No Mails found in " & mbox
            return
        end if
        
        -- Looping over all mails in the inbox mbox and copy the content
        repeat with mail in allMails
            set theMail to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:subject of mail, content:content of mail, visible:true, sender:sender of mail}
            
            -- Send the copied mail
            tell theMail
                -- copy every to recipient
                repeat with oneRecipient in to recipient of mail
                    set theName to name of oneRecipient
                    set theAdress to address of oneRecipient
                    make new to recipient with properties {name:theName, address:theAdress}
                end repeat
                -- copy every bcc recipient
                repeat with oneRecipient in bcc recipient of mail
                    set theName to name of oneRecipient
                    set theAdress to address of oneRecipient
                    make new bcc recipient with properties {name:theName,       address:theAdress}
                end repeat
                -- copy every cc recipient
                repeat with oneRecipient in cc recipient of mail
                    set theName to name of oneRecipient
                    set theAdress to address of oneRecipient
                    make new cc recipient with properties {name:theName, address:theAdress}
                end repeat
                send
                
            end tell
            
            -- Delete the mail in mbox
            delete mail
        end repeat
    end tell
end sendMail

sendMail("8AM")
```

The last line is optional. One needs it for testing the script on its own.

### Timing

The trickier part was the timing. The code snippet below should be seen as a starting point. It works, but there are some issues with it, which I explained further down.

This script gets the `currentTime` and compares it with the `sendtime`. When it is in the interval it calls the other script and sends the mail.

**Code:**

```
on idle
    set currentTime to current date
    -- time when it should be executed (hour * 60 * 60 + min * 60)
    -- here for 8:00 AM
    set sendtime to (8 * 60 * 60 + 0 * 60)
    
    -- if it is between 8 and 8:05 send mails
    if the time of currentTime is greater than sendtime and the time of currentTime is less than (sendtime + 300) then
        
        -- loading the script from the desktop, script in file "send.scpt"
        set sendScript to load script (alias ((path to desktop folder as string) & "send.scpt"))
        -- send Mails from the mailbox "8AM"
        sendMail("8AM") of sendScript
    end if
    
    -- check every day
    return 24 * 60 * 60
end idle

idle {}
```

The last line is optional. One needs it for testing the script on its own, without saving it as an application.

### Issues

- I didn't work out how to wake the computer up at the timing where the script checks the time.
- And whether it is smart to check it only once a day, because if you miss the time frame, the mail probably won't send.
- Furthermore I am not sure whether the internet connection is still there, when not unlocked.

### **Solution**

---

**Use a plugin or a different mail program to use the build in "scheduled send" function ;)
e.g. Spark, Mailbutler, ...**